# Does it make sense to use sidekiq with unicorn?

Tags: multithreading, unicorn, sidekiq

How do they work together? Do we still need to write thread-safe code?

If we have an application what already uses sidekiq and unicorn together, will it make sense to migrate to puma? Or start using resque?

Comment: I'm curious, who are the people responsible for these idiotic names?

Answer (score 1):

Using multi-threaded application servers and asynchronous job frameworks are usually more efficient than multi-process servers, especially if you have an I/O bounded work set.

If you use Unicorn as an app server and Sidekiq as a background job system, you will need to ensure your Rails app and your code are thread-safe.  Most thread safety issues in Rails 3.x/4.x involve class loading or sharing resources like database connections - which will be common to both your front-end application server code and background jobs.

You can find more information about Rails thread safety and connection pooling configuration here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html  The short summary is ensure you enable thread safe mode for class loading and provide a pool of connections slightly larger than the number of active threads.